# How to dd a cookie to CookieContainer from CookieManager

Tags: c#, android, cookies, httpwebrequest, xamarin

Can't find a way to add the cookies I take from the cookiemanager into my HttpWebRequest.. wich I us to send out a SOAP(Where you have to be connected for)

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(_url, _action);
webRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.Instance;
CookieCollection cookieCollection = new CookieCollection();

string cookiestring = cookieManager.GetCookie(_url);

foreach (var pair in cookiestring.Split(' '))
                {
                    string[] cookies = pair.Split('=');
                    cookieCollection.Add(new Cookie(cookies[0], cookies[1]));
                    Console.WriteLine("========NEW COOKIES======");
                    Console.WriteLine(cookies[0] + " " +  cookies[1]);

                }

                try
                {
                    webRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookieCollection);
                }
                catch
                {
                    for(var i = 0; i<100; i++) Console.WriteLine("I'm a failure because I can't even add a stupid cookie");
                }
```

My respons on that is:

========NEW COOKIES======

.ASPXAUTH LONGASSCODE

Meaning he has dat cookie, but when I add the cookiecollection to the webrequest's cookiecontainer it just fails